# run time error '1004' - not able to specify a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have spent hours working on the simplest code to just take a person's input of height and weight, convert the two to meters and kilograms respectively, and calculate the person's BMI. I have worked on the conversions and the logic is simple and working but I cannot specify a range of cells and keep getting this error.

```
Option Explicit

Const KgRate As Double = 0.45359237     'number of kg in one pound
Const PoundsInStone As Integer = 14     'number of pounds in one stone

Const InchesInFeet As Integer = 12      'number of inches in one foot
Const CmsInInch As Double = 2.54        'number of centimetres in an inch


Sub calc_BMI()

'convert height in inches to metres
Range("Sheet1!C7") = ((Range("Sheet1!C4") * InchesInFeet * CmsInInch) + (Range("Sheet1!C5") * CmsInInch)) / 100

'convert stones and pounds to kilograms
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E10:E") = ((Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10:C") * PoundsInStone * KgRate) + (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10:D") * KgRate))

End Sub
```

Comment: "E10:E" is not a range nor is the Range("C10:C")

Comment: Should it be something like Range("C10:C" & lastRow)? The full range reference should look something like e.g. Range("C10:C15")

Comment: @QHarr - Don't forget `.Range("D10:D")`.

Comment: @Jeeped My bad! I didn't even scroll that far. Well spotted.

Comment: Why not store the 4 constants in separate hidden worksheet and name them? Then use them (their names) in normal formulas in worksheet? The Sub can be used to write their Formula or FormulaR1C1.

Comment: @PatricK You don't even need to store the constants in a hidden worksheet.  You can just create a "Name" (Using Formulas / Name Manager) with a name of (for instance) `KgRate` and a "Refers to" of `=0.45359237`.  And then have a formula of (for instance) `=10*KgRate`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the tip, I never has this need and so didn't test it out myself...

Comment: @YowE3K Nice one. I will also be adding that to my bag of tricks. Never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Option Explicit

Const KgRate As Double = 0.45359237     'number of kg in one pound
Const PoundsInStone As Integer = 14     'number of pounds in one stone

Const InchesInFeet As Integer = 12      'number of inches in one foot
Const CmsInInch As Double = 2.54        'number of centimetres in an inch


Sub calc_BMI()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        'convert height in inches to metres
        .Range("C7") = ((.Range("C4") * InchesInFeet * CmsInInch) + (.Range("C5") * CmsInInch)) / 100

        'convert stones and pounds to kilograms
        For i = 10 To N
            .Range("E" & i) = ((.Range("C" & i) * PoundsInStone * KgRate) + (.Range("D" & i) * KgRate))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```